# FFplay keyfile and certificate default path

Tags: ssl, encryption, ffmpeg

I am trying to *manually* decrypt TLS live stream for experimentation. In order to do so, I have to use the private key and certificate on my client. I use FFplay to stream the video. Since the traffic is encrypted, FFplay has to use a private key and a certificate to decrypt the traffic. I assume that there exist a default path to the private key and the certificate. I've been searching for a while but in vain. Any suggestions please?

Comment: what is your output when it fails?

Comment: It doesn't actually fail. I'm searching for the key and cert files

Comment: I believe it uses gnutls or openssl underneath, so check where it integrates there, GL!

Comment: True. I found it in the FFmpeg source code!
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FFmpeg doesn't store the keyfile or the cert in files. They're saved in a structure as in [here](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/e8634fb92e2f624f19ee5fced6481d8ece503119/libavformat/tls_openssl.c). In order to save them, we can modify the source code and compile as indicated [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu)